# Use of Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have a question regarding the following use of Fermat's Little Theorem, quoted from Gallian's Algebra text:

"One case concerned the
number $p=2^{257}-1$. If $p$ is prime, then we know from Fermat’s Little
Theorem that $10^p$ mod $p$ = $10$ mod $p$ and, therefore, $10^{p+1}$ mod $p$ = $100$ mod $p$. Using multiple precision and a simple loop, a computer
was able to calculate $10^{p+1}$ mod $p$ = $10^{2^{257}}$ in a few seconds.
The result was not $100$, and so $p$ is not prime."

My question is why it was necessary to use $p+1$ and not simply check if the original $p$ resulted in 10. What is the use of multiplying by 10?

Comment: It wasn't necessary, but it is easier. You can compute $a^n\bmod k$ quickly by the "method of repeated squaring," which makes the case $n$ a power of $2$ easiest. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: Essentially, the case $n=2^m-1$ case be computed doing $2m-1$ multiplications modulo $k,$ but it takes only $m$ multiplications for $n=2^m.$

Comment: The repeated square method works not only in the case of powers of $2$, with a slight modification it can be applied for every exponent. And for so large exponents, this must be done, no computer can make so many steps in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @Peter As I said, the case $n=2^m-1$ takes $2m-1$ steps, and the case $n=2^m$ takes $m$ steps. It is certainly faster, when dealing with with multiplying two 77-digit numbers and then reducing modulo another $77$-digit number, to do it $257$ times rather than $513$ times. But with modern computers, either way, it really doesn't take long. (And it is easier to compute $m\bmod {2^{257}-1}$ than the general $m\bmod k$ for some other value $k.$)

Comment: Note that we usually even use exponent $p-1$ because then the result must be simply $1$ for every base coprime to the given number. By the way, for $2^p-1$ the Lucas Lehmer test is even more elegant and also proves the primality (if the exponent leads to a  prime).

Comment: The "simple loop" reference is in a quote, and the OP is trying to understand the quote. I don't think OP can answer what is meant by that. @Peter